# PHP: Create JS script from JSON (Convert JSON to JS Object)

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm hosting a JS file through PHP. I want to convert this JSON to JavaScript Object (as a file.js object).

What I have (My JSON):

```
{
    "People": [
        {
            "Name": "Foo Boo",
            "Age": 13,
            "Sex": "Male"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Boo Foo",
            "Age": 15,
            "Sex": "Female"
        }
    ]
}
```

What a want (to JavaScript Object):

```
const People = {
    People: [
        {
            Name: "Foo Boo",
            Age: 13,
            Sex: "Male"
        },
        {
            Name: "Boo Foo",
            Age: 15,
            Sex: "Female"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there some function to remove the double quotes from keys? Or some parameter in `json_encode()` that converts it to a JS Object Text?

```
<?php
$jsonText = '{"People": [{"Name": "Foo Boo","Age": 13,"Sex": "Male"}]}';
$jsObjectText = convertJSONtoJSObject($jsonText);

echo $jsObjectText; //const People = {People: [{Name: "Foo Boo",Age: 13,Sex: "Male"}]}
```

Note: I am not trying to convert a JSON string to a PHP array.

Comment: Why do you need to remove the double quotes? They're perfectly valid in JavaScript objects.

Comment: All JSON is valid JavaScript, but not vice versa.

Comment: `?> const people = <?= $jsonText ?>`

Comment: I think the explanation of JSON is accepted as JS Object Literal, is enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON format makes a perfectly valid JavaScript object. Assuming you have your data in `$people` variable, it's enough to do it like this:

```php
const people = <?= json_encode($people) ?>;
```

If you have a JSON string ready in `$jsonText` and you're 100% sure it's valid JSON, just use it:

```php
const people = <?= $jsonText ?>;
```